# Restrict/Disable browser shortcuts using Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to open an Angular 6 Desktop Application on Browser in Full screen mode. When the user tries to enter desktop shortcuts like Ctrl+T, Ctrl+N, F12 etc. there should be restriction for such events. I cannot disable Ctrl Key because some of the application shortcuts have been overridden.

Is there any other way to handle the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Example you can Detect any Key

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-event-key-yyhswz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**You can avoid following this**

```
if (e.ctrlKey) return;
if (e.ctrlKey) return;
```

Comment: The issue is whenever I try to find the key value for Ctrl+T, browser navigates to New Tab and key values are not captured.

Comment: if (e.ctrlKey && e.ctrlKey) return;

Comment: The condition is same so will return true and return. Some condition to check ctrlKey value and the keyCode for character should work